# Keyerror (key) from none (python)

Tags: python

This is the code I have. I am learning python and this is one of the practice codes from the video. But I am getting an error that I am unable to understand

```
def bytespdate2num(fmt, encoding='utf-8'):
    strconverter = mdates.strpdate2num(fmt)
    def bytesconverter(b):
        s = b.decode(encoding)
        return strconverter(s)
    return bytesconverter


def graph_data(stock):


    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1,1), (0,0))

    stock_price_url = 'http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/'+stock+'/chartdata;type=quote;range=10y/csv'
    source_code = urllib.request.urlopen(stock_price_url).read().decode()
    stock_data = []
    split_source = source_code.split('\n')
    for line in split_source:
        split_line = line.split(',')
        if len(split_line) == 6:
            if 'values' not in line and 'labels' not in line:
                stock_data.append(line)

    date, closep, highp, lowp, openp, volume = np.loadtxt(stock_data,
                                                          delimiter=',',
                                                          unpack=True,
                                                          converters={0: bytespdate2num('%Y%m%d')})

    ax1.plot_date(date, closep,'-', label='Price')
    for label in ax1.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
        label.set_rotation(45)
    ax1.grid(True)#, color='g', linestyle='-', linewidth=5)

    plt.xlabel('Date')
    plt.ylabel('Price')
    plt.title('Interesting Graph\nCheck it out')
    plt.legend()
    plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.09, bottom=0.20, right=0.94, top=0.90, wspace=0.2, hspace=0)
    plt.show()


graph_data('TSLA')
```

The error that I am getting is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sponnag1\workspace\DataAnalysisWithPython\DataAnalysis.py", line 19, in <module>
    from spyder.utils.site.sitecustomize import matplotlib
  File "C:\Users\sponnag1\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 225, in <module>
    if os.environ["QT_API"] == 'pyqt':
  File "C:\Users\sponnag1\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\os.py", line 725, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'QT_API'
```

How do I deal with this?

Comment: Fix your formatting.  You've got code-as-text hanging out above and below your code block, and you need to format the exception message also.

Comment: `QT_API` would imply PyQt, which is a graphic library that matplotlib may be trying to draw with...

Comment: `os.environ["QT_API"]` means it is trying to access an environment variable called QT_API. The KeyError you are getting means this variable is not defined. Do you, in fact, have Qt installed? Seems like spyder package really wants it.

Comment: It ran fine yesterday and when I tried using it today, it gave that error. I have Ot installed. But I am trying to re install it. Hope that solves the problem. :)

Comment: So I opened up a new project on eclipse and tried to execute the same program and it ran fine. I dont know why it did not work. I will continue to find the reason behind the problem. Thank you.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you manage to fix it? @SurajNagabhushana

Comment: I opened up a new project, copy pasted the entire code as it is and it worked. I don't know why yet! Let me know if that works out for you.! :)

Answer (score 0):

`os.environ["QT_API"]` means it is trying to access an environment variable called QT_API. The KeyError you are getting means this variable is not defined. It looks like you might be using a `--matplotlib=qt` flag, but do not, in fact,  have Qt installed.

Comment: It ran fine yesterday and when I tried using it today, it did not. I have Ot installed. But I am trying to re install it. Hope that solves the problem